# webpack bundle.js not found - 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm trying to learn Webpack configuration, and I keep getting errors in my console. It seems like my webpack app.bundle.js is not been found.

The page loads and the content of my html file displays, but not in the app.bundle.js or the html file in have in my dist directory, not untill i run mpm build.

below is the code for the webpack configuration and the error

```
// import node.js native path module
const path  = require('path');
let webpack = require('webpack');

//require HtmlWebPackPlugin
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//define constant for paths
const paths ={
 DIST: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
 SRC: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
JS: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js')
};

console.log(paths.DIST);

//webpack configuration
module.exports ={
entry: path.join(paths.JS, 'index.js'),
output: {
    path: paths.DIST,
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
},

//set starting point for server
devServer: {
    contentBase: paths.SRC,
    host:'localhost',
    port: port,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: true,
    hot:true
},

//set webpack to use plugins
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.join(paths.SRC, 'index.html'),
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.bundle.css'),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
],

//configure loaders
module: {
    rules: [

        //setup babel loader
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                'babel-loader',
            ],
        },

        //setup css loader
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: 'css-loader',
            }),
        },

        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
              'file-loader',
            ],
          },
    ],
},

//enable JS files without adding their extensions
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
},

};
```

Here is the error on the browser console

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:3000/js/app.bundle.js”

Source map error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL: http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js Source Map URL: sockjs.js.map
```

Comment: You're outputting your JS to the `dist` directory

Comment: Try adding a `publicPath` to your output: `output: {
    path: paths.DIST,
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
}`

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath

Comment: @Max Baldwin, I do not understand what you are pointing at.

Comment: You're file path is wrong. You're failed path is `http://localhost:3000/js/app.bundle.js`. You're not outputting to the `js` directory. You're outputting to the `dist` directory.

Comment: @Max Baldwin, have you taken a look at the code I posted above? My output is defined correctly unless I don't understand the place you are pointing out.

Comment: You're `output` key in your configurations points to your `dist` directory. Not your `js` directory. Your script tag should not point to `http://localhost:3000/js/app.bundle.js` it should point to `http://localhost:3000/dist/app.bundle.js`

Comment: You are looking at the error, not the configuration I posted. What you are observing is what I am trying to figure out. I don't know why it is so because that is not what is contained in my config file.

Answer (score 1):

The post is old but hopefully this helps some future person since I just solved a similar issue, here goes:

Ensure that the server root path and the output path makes sense for the files generating the 404 error.
Specifically, the server root path, set by "contentBase: paths.SRC" points to the SRC folder but the JS files are output to paths.DIST. When a browser attempts to access these files the URL it uses points to the wrong location. Fix by either changing content base to DIST, or adding `publicPath: paths.DIST,` which will override contentbase.

Link to references for [contentBase](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase), and [publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-publicpath-).

Answer (score 0):

The same error happened to me because i didn't run Webpack.

```
npx webpack
```

Run it on the same directory as Webpack configuration script.